# Can't create unnormalized histogram using seaborn with full values represented in plot

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, seaborn

I have a CSV file named data.csv that has three columns:

```
vendor,sample
A,3
A,2
B,1
A,1
....
```

I'd like to take everything that has the first column = A and create a histogram in seaborn that shows the number of occurrences that a sample shows up. don't want the data to be normalized. When I attempt to plot this, the y-axis is much smaller than the actual value. for example, in the code below, there are 708 occurrences of "1" but in the histogram, 1 only goes up to 30 on the y-axis.

```
data = pd.read_csv(r'C:\data\data.csv')
v1=list(data[data['Vendor'] == 'A']['Sample'])
print(str(v1))


sns.distplot(v1,norm_hist=False)
count=0
for i in v1:
    if i == 1:
        count = count+1
print(str(count))
```

Output:

```
[3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1,1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 6, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 4, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 4, 4, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 1, 2, 4, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 8, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 6, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 6, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 6, 3, 3, 3, 3, 6, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3]
708
```

[image: output]

I'd like the histogram to correctly represent the number of occurences for each sample value for vendor "A" and well as the numerical value above the bar.

Comment: @JohanC  That worked, Please respond so that I can accept your anser and you get credit for it.

Comment: Still not able to add text to heights...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`distplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.distplot.html) has a parameter `kde` which is default True. It is meant to draw a ["kernel density estimation"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation) over the histogram. This only can be drawn together well with the histogram if both are normalized. Such a kde tries to mimic the underlying probability distribution function (pdf). This is not meaningful for discrete distributions. To have a non-normalized `distplot`, the parameter `kde=False` should be set explicitly.

To annotate the heights of the bars, one can loop through the generated patches, get their height, their position and their width to put a text at the appropriate position. Adding '\n' to the string puts the text with a nice little padding just above the bar.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

# v1 = [3,2,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,1,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,1,...]
plot = sns.distplot(v1, kde=False)
for bar in plot.patches:
    h = bar.get_height()
    if h != 0:
        plot.text(bar.get_x() + bar.get_width() / 2,
                  h,
                  f'{h:.0f}\n',
                  ha='center',
                  va='center')
plt.show()
```

[image: demo plot]